Keypad not working issue Ubuntu 24.04
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and 20.04. Our laptop keypad is not working. However in the BIOS setting the keypad is working fine. Processor is an intel ALDERLAKE i3 1215u.
Please help me in resolving this issue.
Any inputs are most welcome.

How do you know the keypad works in BIOS? What have you tried to fix this? Please add to the question with edit what steps you have taken and the results.
